# Why do I need to run "npm install -g angular/cli" everytime for the same Angular project that i'm working on still?

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular project.
What happened is that morning I installed the latest angular version and working on a project till I got exhausted. After that I shutdown my system and was away for some time.
When I started the same project again and ran the command "ng serve" in VSC in the terminal it was showing as below -
"ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- ng serve
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
    Then I installed Angular again and now ng started working.

Is there any way to avoid installing Angular again and again for the same project which we are working on in the system??
Can we set the Angular path as global such that we can avoid installing for different projects in the system??

Comment: So even though your project uses a specific version of Angular as defined in package.json, you want to bypass using the defined version and instead use a global version, regardless of what that version number is or its compatibility with your application?

Comment: Nope I just wanted to use the same version.
The thing is that when ran ng serve it was throwing the error that the command is not found itself

Comment: It's because your default terminal is probably **PowerShell (PS)** or some other non-system-standard. 

If you switch to "**Command Prompt (cmd)**" terminal, you'll have access to the global `ng` CLI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdkAR.png

or just run "cmd" in your PS terminal.

Comment: If you want to use the same version then run it via `npm`, not using the globally installed package whose version is not kept in sync.

Comment: Like npm run ??

Answer (score 1):

It's because your default terminal is probably **PowerShell (PS)** or some other non-system-standard.

If you switch to "**Command Prompt (cmd)**" terminal, you'll have access to the global `ng` CLI:

[image: Terminal in VSCode]

Or just run `cmd` from your PS terminal.